# How to do unpack this nested tuple in better way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I got a tuple called records

```
records =(['foo', 1]),(['bar', 'hello'])
```

This is the Expected_result

```
expected_result= (['foo','bar'],['1','hello'])
```

I created a For loop for the above and its doing well

```
for i in range(len(records[0])):
    for k in range(len(records[1])):
        if i==k:
            j,v = records
            print(j[i],v[i])
```

Is there any better way to do this using minimum code and lines ?

Regards

Comment: Are these always going to be 2-tuples? If so, you don't really need the nested loops. Also, what's going to happen if `records` has more than 2 tuples?

Comment: yes,..They are 2-tuples  @DeepSpace

Answer (score 5):

For list of tuples:

```
records =(['foo', 1]),(['bar', 'hello'])

expected_result = list(zip(*records))
expected_result 

[('foo', 'bar'), (1, 'hello')]
```

For tuple of lists:

```
expected_result = tuple(map(list,zip(*records)))
expected_result

(['foo', 'bar'], [1, 'hello'])
```

For tuple of tuples:

```
expected_result = tuple(zip(*records))
expected_result

(('foo', 'bar'), (1, 'hello'))
```

Comment: Just a a tiny nitpicking: OP wants a tuple of lists. This returns a list of tuples.

Comment: the result is in a list,not a tuple. ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to return a tuple of lists:

```
records = (['foo', 1]), (['bar', 'hello'])
res = tuple(map(list, zip(*records)))

# (['foo', 'bar'], [1, 'hello'])
```

Unlike your desired output, `1` will remain an integer.

Comment: seems complicated also pythonic .. :)

Comment: The good news is these built-ins are highly optimized. No Python-level `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

A more pythonic way would be to make an iterator with the function **zip**.

For example:

```
result = list(zip(*records))
```

will return a list of two tuples:

```
[('foo', 'bar'), (1, 'hello')]
```

You get your expected result (one tuple of two lists) by using both **list** and **tuple** constructors:

```
expected_result = tuple(list(item) for item in zip(*records))
print(expected_result)

(['foo', 'bar'], [1, 'hello'])
```